# How to convert a Google Places photo_reference into a URL

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api

I am currently developing a Restaurant finder application that allows the users to search for Restaurant's around them. I am using a List Adapter to display a list of nearby Restaurants, the only issue I am having is with displaying the photos of those Restaurants.

Looking at the Google Places Photos API I understand that for each Restaurant that has a photo there is a photo_reference attribute. So what I am trying to do is use the ImageLoader library to display all these photos in my list.

The problem here is that ImageLoader requires a URL of the photo but the Google Places API uses a photo_reference. How can I convert a photo_reference into a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the `photo_reference` in a URL.

E.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY

See the [Place Photo Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#place_photo_requests) documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this already but kept getting the HTTP 403 error. I have checked my quota and it has not been exceeded.

Comment: I generated a new web browser key and it works now, thanks again!

Comment: But its so strange why did I need to generate a new key, I never exceeded my quota?

Comment: Perhaps you had an IP restriction configured on the key?  The body or headers of the 403 response will probably contain information indicating why the request failed.

Comment: Ah ok, the 403 response was just an image there were no messages. But thanks anyway.